How to automatically run pull requests from an Azure DevOps pipeline
I'm trying to write a pipeline in Azure DevOps that can look at some code I write in VSCode and automatically add., commit, and push it without me every having to do anything in the console. Here is the code I have so far
trigger:
- main

pool: Agent Pool

steps:
- script: |
    git checkout azure-pipelines 
    git pull origin main --rebase 
    git add .
    git commit -m "New Commit"
    git push -f origin main
  displayName: 'Push Code' 

I was able to simplify it down to this but the problem has remained constant. No matter what I do, it will not commit anything I have in VSCode. I had a URL origin check at one point but that only seemed to confuse the program. So I guess I have two questions on this

How can I check what URL my Azure Repo is in VSCode?
Is what I am trying to do even possible with a pipeline and, if so, how can I do it better than this?


Apologies, this is my first time writing something on StackOverflow and it messed up the spacing

Hi @jrmj4495, Welcome to SO. Your pipeline will by default check out the latest version of your code from the cloud repo. As far as I understood, you would expect the pipeline to retrieve the code from VSCode. Was that code from the local workspace of your VSCode and never pushed into the cloud repo? If that is the case, I don't believe it is a job that a pipeline should do. May I ask why not you directly push the commit from local workspace into cloud repo via VSCode, so that the pipeline can get all the changes?

If it is possible for you to push the commit from the local VSCode workspace to the source branch of PR, say the dev branch, you may create a pipeline to be triggered by this commit and create a PR using Aure DevOps CLI, API or extension task to merge the code from dev branch into the target main branch.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT Hi there and thanks for the reply. While I agree that it would just be easier to push manually from VSCode in this instance, this task is what the bosses want :/ So I gotta find a way for it to work. I'll investigate your second comment, as it sounds promising, and see what I can do. Thank you!

Hi @jrmj4495, Glad to be of help and thanks for the update. Hope the demo design below to create PR in the pipeline triggered by a CI commit may help. Good luck with the work to go and cheers!

Based on the discussions, if it is possible for you to trigger the pipeline by the commit pushed from the local VSCode workspace onto the remote PR source branch, for example dev branch, you may consider creating a new PR with the help of az repos pr create command in a pipeline task.
Since it only creates a new PR, we can even skip the checkout step to get the code pushed from local branch.
Here is a sample YAML pipeline for your reference, which leverages several pipeline predefined variables. Please also note that the command running in the sample below authenticates against the $(System.AccessToken) of the pipeline service account, therefore we need to make sure the corresponding or both pipeline service accounts to the job authorization scope in your organization and project settings has sufficient permissions to create a PR.
trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: none
- pwsh: |
    az repos pr create `
      --org $(System.CollectionUri) `
      --project $(System.TeamProject) `
      --repository $(Build.Repository.Name) `
      --source-branch $(Build.SourceBranchName) `
      --target-branch master `
      --title "PR: dev to master"
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)


To complete a PR merge, you may refer to my answer in another recent post.
